# Using Facebook-SDK with OWIN/Katana

Tags: asp.net-web-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, single-page-application, owin, katana

I want to use Facebook-SDK login popup at my SPA WEBAPI application with OWIN. VS 2013 already provides a great template for facebook login but it highly dependent on server side codes which i don't prefer. 
By using Facebook-SDK, i can login to facebook and access the user_id, access_token etc., after this point, i send the access_token to /signin-facebook?code=[access_token], however, i get access_denied error. I guess it is because i intervene the owin workflow and don't send correlation cookie.

To sum up, is it possible to bypass first 3 steps in the login flow in this [picture](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx) if I already have the access_token?

Comment: Hi.  Did you ever resolve this?  I have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for late respond but maybe this will be helpful for others.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092723/webapi-asp-net-identity-facebook-login  Implicit authorization was what i was looking for. If you want to learn more about implicit flow https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.2