# How to create Refresh Token with External Login Provider?

Tags: asp.net, oauth

I have searched over the web and could not find a solution to my problem. I am implementing OAuth in my app. I am using ASP .NET Web API 2, and Owin. The scenario is this, once a user request to the Token end point, he or she will receive an access token along with a refresh token to generate a new access token. I have a class the helps me to generate a refresh token. Here is it :

```
   public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
    {


       private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> _refreshTokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket>();



    public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {

            var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                var refreshTokenLifeTime = context.OwinContext.Get<string>                                    ("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime");
                var token = new RefreshToken() 
                { 
                    Id = Helper.GetHash(refreshTokenId),
                    ClientId = clientid, 
                    Subject = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
                    IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)
                };
                context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedUtc;
                context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = token.ExpiresUtc;
                token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();
                var result = await _repo.AddRefreshToken(token);
                if (result)
                {        
                    context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
                }
            }
        }

        // this method will be used to generate Access Token using the Refresh Token
        public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {

            string hashedTokenId = Helper.GetHash(context.Token);
            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                var refreshToken = await _repo.FindRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);
                if (refreshToken != null )
                {
                    //Get protectedTicket from refreshToken class
                    context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
                    // one refresh token per user and client
                    var result = await _repo.RemoveRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

now i am allowing my users to register through facebook. Once a user register with facebook, I generate an access token and give it to him.  Should I generate a refresh token as well ? Onething comes to my mind, is to generate a long access token like one day, then this user has to login with facebook again. But if i do not want to do that, I can give the client, a refresh token, and he can use it to refresh the generated access token and get a new. How do I create the refresh token and attach it to the response when someone register or login with facebook or externally ?

Here is my external registration API

```
  public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
      [AllowAnonymous]
      [Route("RegisterExternal")]
      public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterExternal(RegisterExternalBindingModel model)
      {

         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
         }
         var accessTokenResponse = GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse(model.UserName);
         return Ok(accessTokenResponse);
      }


    }
```

// Private method to generate access token

```
private JObject GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse(string userName)
        {

            var tokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
            var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(tokenExpiration),
            };
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
            var accessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
            JObject tokenResponse = new JObject(
                                        new JProperty("userName", userName),
                                        new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
                                        // Here is what I need
                                        new JProperty("resfresh_token", GetRefreshToken()),
                                        new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
                                        new JProperty("refresh_token",refreshToken),
                                        new JProperty("expires_in", tokenExpiration.TotalSeconds.ToString()),
                                        new JProperty(".issued", ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc.ToString()),
                                        new JProperty(".expires", ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.ToString())
        );
            return tokenResponse;
        }
```

Comment: Any updates on that topic? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 29):

I spent a lot of time to find the answer to this question. So, i'm happy to help you.

1) Change your ExternalLogin method.
It usually looks like:

```
if (hasRegistered)
{
     Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

     ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
     ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

     AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
     Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
}
```

Now, actually, it is necessary to add refresh_token. 
Method will look like this:

```
if (hasRegistered)
{
     Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

     ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                   OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
     ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

     AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);

     // ADD THIS PART
     var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
     var accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

                Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context = 
                    new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
                        Request.GetOwinContext(), 
                        Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat, ticket);

     await Startup.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync(context);
     properties.Dictionary.Add("refresh_token", context.Token);

     Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
}
```

Now the refrehs token will be generated.

2) There is a problem to use basic context.SerializeTicket in SimpleRefreshTokenProvider CreateAsync method. 
Message from [Bit Of Technology](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/)

> Seems in the ReceiveAsync method, the context.DeserializeTicket is not
>   returning an Authentication Ticket at all in the external login case.
>   When I look at the context.Ticket property after that call it’s null.
>   Comparing that to the local login flow, the DeserializeTicket method
>   sets the context.Ticket property to an AuthenticationTicket. So the
>   mystery now is how come the DeserializeTicket behaves differently in
>   the two flows. The protected ticket string in the database is created
>   in the same CreateAsync method, differing only in that I call that
>   method manually in the GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse, vs. the Owin
>   middlware calling it normally… And neither SerializeTicket or
>   DeserializeTicket throw an error…

So, you need to use Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer to searizize and deserialize ticket. 
It will be look like this:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer serializer
                = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer();

token.ProtectedTicket = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(serializer.Serialize(context.Ticket));
```

instead of:

```
token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();
```

And for ReceiveAsync method:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer serializer = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer();
context.SetTicket(serializer.Deserialize(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket)));
```

instead of:

```
context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
```

3) Now you need to add refresh_token to ExternalLogin method response.
Override AuthorizationEndpointResponse in your OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider. Something like this:

```
public override Task AuthorizationEndpointResponse(OAuthAuthorizationEndpointResponseContext context)
{
     var refreshToken = context.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Properties.Dictionary["refresh_token"];
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
     {
          context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("refresh_token", refreshToken);
     }
     return base.AuthorizationEndpointResponse(context);
}
```

So.. thats all! Now, after calling ExternalLogin method, you get url:
https://localhost:44301/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=bearer&expires_in=300&state=STATE&refresh_token=TICKET&returnUrl=URL

I hope this helps)

Comment: thanks, for your effort. Actually I was using this code for a project I stopped working on it. However, I will try this code, once I start working on it again and I will let you know my feedback. But again, thanks so much for your effort I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad to help) Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: First of all thank you for your solution. For some reason though, it does not work for me.
As soon as I use an external login provider, I do get the refresh_token, but when I try to use it to get a new access token, I get an 400 Bad Request error with the body:
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
There are no exceptions on the server and I just do not know how to debug this. :-| (Tried your solution and the one proposed by @Wouter Crooy)
Could you create a sample solution, or give me any hints?

Comment: Alexander, are your sure that refresh_token that you received is valid? Message {"error":"invalid_grant"} сan be obtained if the token is invalid/expired/incorrectly serialized. Try to debug method ReceiveAsync/Receive in RefreshTokenProvider, make sure the token is stored in the database and correctly deserialized.

Comment: Thanks, successfully implemented this with normal login. Don't forget to validate your client_id though when doing it this way!

Answer (score 8):

@giraffe and others offcourse

A few remarks. There's no need to use the *custom* tickerserializer.

The following line:

```cs
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context = 
                new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
                    Request.GetOwinContext(), 
                    Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat, ticket);
```

As tokenformat: `Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat` is used. Since we want to provide a refeshtoken this needs te be changed to:  `Startup.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenFormat`

Otherwise if you want to get a new accesstoken and refresh the refreshtoken ( grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=...... ) the deserializer/unprotector will fail. Since it uses the wrong purposes keywords at the decrypt stage.

Comment: Thanks for comment! Maybe you are right, but in my case, the process is working correctly.Next time I'll try to implement your variant!

Answer (score 6):

Finally found the solution for my problem.
First of all, if you EVER encounter any problems with OWIN and you cannot figure out what is going wrong, I advise you to simply enable symbol-debugging and debug it. A great explanation can be found here:
http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio

My mistake simply was, that I was calculating a wrong ExiresUtc when using external login providers. So my refreshtoken basically was always expired right away....

If you are implementing refresh tokens, then look at this gread blog article:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

And to make it work with refresh tokens for external providers, you have to set the two requried parameters ("as:clientAllowedOrigin" and "as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime") on the context
so instead of

```
 var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
var context = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
                    Request.GetOwinContext(), 
                    Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat, ticket);

 await Startup.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync(context);
 properties.Dictionary.Add("refresh_token", context.Token);
```

you need to get the client first and set the context parameters

```
    // retrieve client from database
    var client = authRepository.FindClient(client_id);
    // only generate refresh token if client is registered
    if (client != null)
    {
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        var context = new AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(Request.GetOwinContext(), AuthConfig.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenFormat, ticket);
        // Set this two context parameters or it won't work!!
        context.OwinContext.Set("as:clientAllowedOrigin", client.AllowedOrigin);
        context.OwinContext.Set("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime", client.RefreshTokenLifeTime.ToString());

        await AuthConfig.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync(context);
        properties.Dictionary.Add("refresh_token", context.Token);
    }
```