# OAuth implict grant flow and refresh token

Tags: angularjs, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

For now I have Asp.Net WebAPI and client application (Angular) on separate hosts. As for authentication, WebAPI uses default external OAuth provider (Google) implementation with middlewares, external bearer token and cookie. Since web application is being hosted separately, for security reasons it is using Implicit grant flow, so access_token is being returned after hash symbol in URI. Also, it means that refresh token can not be implemented.

Here comes the part I am a bit confused about.
As for my WebAPI I am using Local accounts, which have to be created for every new user that comes to my application externaly (from Google) using basic information it provides. So the external bearer token and cookie are only used till I register the user, sign him in and provide LOCAL AUTHORITY bearer token which can be used to access secured API endpoints. It means I still have the LOCAL AUTHORITY provider which lives in my WebAPI and manages access_tokens.

Does it mean that I can implement refresh token?
If I understand correctly refresh token is not valid between Google and my app (because it is using implicit grant flow), but it is viable between my WebAPI and Client application without leaving security holes?

I am a bit confused about the refresh token here. Is it possible?

Thanks for your time.

**Kind of Solution**
[Read this answer for the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739710/how-to-create-refresh-token-with-external-login-provider)