# Handling server redirect to Facebook login page in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have an AngularJS app, and a WebApi2 with ASP.NET Identity 2.0.
I am trying to log user in using Facebook account.

I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358918/1269414) to do it.

Getting auth providers is easy, I have problem with the next step.
It says, I should make GET request to my WebApi server, using the Url provided before.
So I make my call and get a `HTTP 302` with `Location` header set to facebook's login page.

The browser doesn't redirect, however.
In Developer Tools I see that GET request to this address is made, but then in console there is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url here]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' therefore not allowed access.
```

I know this is related to CORS, but like it expects CORS enabled on Facebook's side?

From what I understand: after loggin to Facebook, it redirects me back to my WebApi method registering ExternalLogin, and than back to my AngularApp. Is that correct?

Here's code of my login function:

```
function facebookLogin() {
    getExternalLogins().then(function (data) {
        var providerData = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            if(data[i].Name == 'Facebook'){
                providerData = data[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if(providerData != null) {
             window.location.href = serverBaseUrl + providerData.Url;
        }

    },
    function (error, status) {

    });
}
```

#### Update:

I've managed to redirect to Facebook's login page, thanks to CBroe's comment.
The next problem is that after logging in, Facebook redirects me to my WebApi.
How can I redirect user back to Angular app? WebApi can be called from various places, not only from example.com but from example1.com or example2.com also.

Maybe it would be a better idea to perform this login client-side using Facebook API, and then notify the server about it?
But how to perform login on WebApi using FB authResponse?

Comment: You are not supposed to make that call in the background – you have to redirect the user to the login URL.

Comment: OK, but how to do it? Server sends 302 which should redirect, but that doesn't happen. Perhaps there is another way, instead of `$http` ?

Comment: It does not happen because you are using AJAX where you should _not_ be using it. Simply “load” the URL (the original, before the redirect) in the browser, f.e. by assigning it to `location.href`.

Comment: Fabebook allows you a callback url which it can redirect to after login completes, you should set this to a url that will simply handle whatever info facebook passes back to you

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible in my case. WebApi could handle the response and authenticate user, but my Angular app is on different host - what's more it could be on any number of hosts. I wouldn't know where to redirect from WebApi to my Angular app. That's why I opted for JS SDK instead of server-side authentication.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this @rakoczyn? I'm facing something similar

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps, they solved the issue for me (for a different login provider):

1. Remove the built-in login page and controller, and the option to use
   ASP.Net identity from the web application; see [this article](http://coding.abel.nu/2014/11/using-owin-external-login-without-asp-net-identity/).
2. Add credentials in the $.ajax call (see below) of in [$http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741533/angularjs-withcredentials):

```js
 xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
            },
```

3. Add to your web.config the following to enable CORS:

```html
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="FACEBOOK_APP_URL" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
```